# Copying xls file from FileInputStream to FileWriter corrupts the file

Tags: java, io, filewriter

Why is it that when I try to use any Writer implementation to copy the contents of an excel file content of the file gets corrupted !! .

```
 @Test
        public void testExcelCopy1() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

            IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("d:\\temp\\123.xls")), new OutputStreamWriter(
                            new FileOutputStream("d:\\temp\\1234.xls")));

            Assert.assertArrayEquals(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("d:\\temp\\123.xls"))
                            , FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("d:\\temp\\1234.xls")));
        }

        @Test
        public void testExcelCopy2() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

            IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("d:\\temp\\123.xls")), new FileOutputStream("d:\\temp\\12345.xls"));

            Assert.assertArrayEquals(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("d:\\temp\\123.xls"))
                            , FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("d:\\temp\\12345.xls")));
        }
```

[Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr9xU.png)

I have a reqiurement where in I need to write a Workbook  created with Apache Poi API into a Writer Implementation !! and I am stuck with this issue !! Can anyone help ?!!

Update :

I understand the problem is when I try to convert a byte stream into a char stream . but i don't get why .

This test also fails !!

```
@Test
    public void testExcelCopy1() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("d:\\temp\\123.xls"));
        Writer write = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("d:\\temp\\1234.xls"));
        IOUtils.copy(reader, write);
        write.flush();
        write.close();

        Assert.assertArrayEquals(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("d:\\temp\\123.xls"))
                        , FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("d:\\temp\\1234.xls")));
    }
```

Comment: Because you are trying to write a binary stream with a character based API

Comment: Does it mean there is no way i can do this ! . I want to write a byte array of excel content into a Writer Implementation . Is there any other way ?! .

Comment: You shall use binary streams apis to write binary data. Why do you need to put a reader/writer implementation over it

Comment: OK . actually need is that I need to write the Workbook that I created using Apache POI API into a Writer Implementation , but the workbook api only supports writing into a output stream !!,..Workbook.write(OutputStream) .. so my basic need here is that I have byte array and I need to write into a FileWriter .. which doesn't work the way I thought it will !! ..

Answer (score 0):

The methods in IOUtils will not flush or close the stream by itself, wherever possible. The caller is considered responsible to close the stream.

Please flush and close the streams and try!

> Wherever possible, the methods in this class do not flush or close the
>   stream. This is to avoid making non-portable assumptions about the
>   streams' origin and further use. Thus the caller is still responsible
>   for closing streams after use.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Comment: Thnx , That doesn't seem to fix the problem . I wonder whether there is any problem in converting from byte array to char array in case of excel content !! because the same works fine for a text file .

Answer (score 0):

I understand now it is technically not correct to try reading the content of an Excel or any other OLE2 object using any char based reader which works only for text files. I worked around my problem . Thanks

Bottom line is Reader and Writer works only for txt , xml , json , csv etc. not for doc , xls or any other ms office files .

Thanks anyway guys

Comment: Good that you find it .. :)